# I'm starting download, unknown size

Tags: php, file, download

I start a download using PHP with this code:

```
<?
$_REQUEST['file'] = urldecode($_GET['file']);

header("Content-type: application/x-file-to-save");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_REQUEST['file']);
readfile($_REQUEST['file']);
?>
```

It works, but the download is with unknown size ans no ETA...

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
header("Content-length: ". filesize($_REQUEST['file']));
```